# Create a custom draw Toolbar

Tags: leaflet, javascript, leaflet-draw, toolbar

I would like to create my own custom toolbar for `leaflet.draw` plugin but I don't know how to approach this solution.

To be more clear, I am trying to create a side-panel with buttons for each action, and with each `onclick` event I call the draw action (replace the default toolbar with a custom one).

Is that even possible?

Comment: Well, start with the existing ones https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw and https://github.com/justinmanley/leaflet-draw-toolbar

Comment: I just updated my question, and thanks for the suggestion although I would like to replace the default toolbar, that is not very stylish.

Comment: I saw this but I am new to javascript and I cant quite understand how to bind the draw event to a function so i can call it on onclick event